# How to implement a simple web service with token-based access using KeyCloak?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I want to create a web service that would work in the following way:

1. The client contats KeyCloak and provides user name and password.
2. KeyCloak returns an access token to the client.
3. Using that access token the client access a page protected by KeyCloak.

How can I do it?

**What I tried**

**Step 1: The client gets an access token**

```
private String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
    final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "test-app"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "user1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));


    try {
        final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token");
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        final CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        System.out.println(String.format("Result: %d", statusCode));

        if (statusCode != 200) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            return null;
        }

        final String responseTxt = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseTxt);

        final String accessToken = json.getString("access_token");
        return accessToken;
    } finally {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work as I get a response code 200 and the access token in the body.

**Step 2: Access the protected web service**

The web service is running at `http://127.0.0.1:8090/test`.

I'm using the following code to access it (`accessToken` is the access token from previous step):

```
    final String targetUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/test";
    final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(targetUrl);
    get.setHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer%s", accessToken));
    final CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    System.out.println(String.format("Result: %d", statusCode));
    client.close();
```

When I do this, I get the login page of KeyCloak as a response, not the response of the web service.

**How is the web service configured?**

Here is the actual web service:

```
@RestController
public class SampleRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test*")
                .hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
server.port = 8090

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true


keycloak.realm = myrealm 
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = test-app
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/test/*
```

What do I need to change in order to get "Hello, world!" response when I send a request with the access token in the header?

**Update 1:** I found one part of the problem -- wrong configuration of the client. It should be `bearer only`.

[image: Screenshot]

But now I'm getting the response `Bearer-only applications are not allowed to initiate browser login`.

**Update 2:** With the following service configuration, it works.

```
server.port = 8090
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
keycloak.realm = myrealm
keycloak.resource = test-app
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.principal-attribute = preferred_username
```

Comment: you configure your Keycloak for beare, but not server

Comment: You need to make the KC client you use to log in public or confidential, not bearer-only. The bearer-only clients are not meant to be used in the authentication flow. The flow you're using to authenticate is the direct access grant, which is used for compatibility, but for brand new applications the authorization code flow is much preferable. By the way, I see another issue in your code, for building the `Authorization` header you use `String.format("Bearer%s", accessToken))`, I guess it should be `String.format("Bearer %s", accessToken))`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect flow or destinations. If you want to use login/password you could choose 2 of them:

1. current. you try to access, your server check your login and if you are not - redirect to keycloak. After login, keycloak redirect you to your page (or login page - I don't remember) with **access_code (not token)**. After this your service send this code to keycloak and do other stuff
2. Change flow to password flow. In this case you'll send username/password to your service (not Keycloak), your service send this credentials to Keycloak and after that do another stuff

**UPDATE:**

I prefer that for users use first stuff, but if you need login by other program, than better to use another mechanism. `ClientCredentials` or custom user with small scope of roles

**UPDATE2:**

If you really need to use auth token, you could implement custom [AccessTokenProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenProvider.html) and customize your `OAuth2RestTemplate` using [UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/UserInfoRestTemplateCustomizer.html). But it's not too easy

Comment: I need to use the flow where I first get the access token (or code), and then connect to the application using that code. See also my update 1.